# Delete github branch with spaces in it

Tags: git, github

I have two git branches named:

```
master
master (1)
```

I'd like to delete the "master (1)" branch and ensure that in doing so I don't delete "master".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically git does not allow you to have branch name with spaces.
This can occur when you use a sync software like dropbox, copy etc.

In order to delete the branch do one of the following:

#### Remove the branch file (option 1)

Open file explorer, navigate to your `.git/ref/heads` folder and delete the file from the folder.

#### Use quotes (option 2)

```bash
# Force the deletion of the branch (_D)
git branch -D "master (1)"
```

Comment: Is it necessary to do both steps? Doing just the git branch -D "master (1)" seemed to work.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap into quotes:

```
git branch -D "master (1)"
```